# How do I cast a Hash into an object in ruby?

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I am using Mongo and storing a hash in the database.  However later on when I retrieve the hash, I can no longer use my object methods?  How can I cast the retrieved Hash from the database into a TraitScore???

```
class TraitScore < Hash
  def initialize(attrs = {}, options = nil)
    self['net']    = attrs[:net]   || 0.0
    self['total']  = attrs[:total] || 0.0
    self['score']  = attrs[:score] || 0.0
  end

  def inc_net(val)
    self['net'] += val
  end

  def inc_total(val)
    self['total'] += (val || 0).abs
  end

  def set_score(score)
    self['score'] = score
  end
end
```

Comment: ...`TraitScore.new(hash)`?

Comment: You cannot 'cast' one object to another class in Ruby (except via `evil.rb`; Google it). You can only create a _new_ object based on an existing object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging by the source code, it looks like that's exactly what `TraitScore`'s initialize method does.

```
irb(main):001:0> hash = {net: 0.0, total: 5, score: 7}
=> {:net=>0.0, :total=>5, :score=>7}
irb(main):002:0> hash.class
=> Hash
irb(main):003:0> object = TraitScore.new(hash)
=> {"net"=>0.0, "total"=>5, "score"=>7}
irb(main):004:0> object.class
=> TraitScore
```